# How to check for all the versions of a chef cookbook?

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, knife

How to check for all the versions of a chef cookbook?
I have a cookbook called 'sample', how to create multiple versions of it and check using knife command line tools?

Answer (score 1):

Versions are "created" when you upload them to a Chef Server. You can see which versions exist in the Chef Server via `knife cookbook show sample`.

Comment: I have uploaded cookbook  multiple times to server, but still it is showing only one version.

Comment: I guess I need to change metadata.rb file for different versions. Right?

Comment: Did you change the `version` field in your `metadata.rb` between uploads? If not, then you have been overwriting a single version each time. You can prevent this by doing "frozen" uploads (the default with Berkshelf) via `knife cookbook upload --frozen`.

Answer (score 1):

`knife cookbook list --all` shows all versions (of all cookbooks) currently uploaded to Chef Server.